# Strange LINQ Error When Using A Variable But Not a Hard-coded String

Tags: linq-to-entities, sql-server-ce

I have a simple LINQ query running on top of Entity Framework (v1) and pointing at SQL Server Compact v3.5 SP2 (8085):

```
var myResults = (from m in myContext.MyData
                 join o in myContext.SomeOtherData on new { m.ID, Name = myNameVariable } equals new { o.ID, o.Name }
                 select m).ToArray();
```

The above query will fail with the following error:

> The specified argument value for the
>   function is not valid. [ Argument # =
>   1,Name of function(if known) = isnull
>   ]

If I change the query by simply replacing the myNameVariable with a hard-coded string, it works. For instance:

```
var myResults = (from m in myContext.MyData
                 join o in myContext.SomeOtherData on new { m.ID, Name = "SomeNameValue"} equals new { o.ID, o.Name }
                 select m).ToArray();
```

What is going on here? I am 100% positive that myNameVariable is set to a valid string. It is definitely *not* null.

Comment: did you try removing Name = myNameVariable with myNameVariable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If I replace "Name = myNameVariable" with just "myNameVariable", that will change the signature of the anonymous type and cause the expression to fail.

Comment: As an aside, this stuff all works if I simply do my join on ID and use a where clause to filter down the name. So that's a work around if we can't get this working.

Comment: What's even more interesting is that some queries that use this exact join patter work fine, while others fail. It seems to be a fluke in the way the expressions are evaluated by EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EF generates different SQL for these queries.

For the hard-coded string, it uses a string literal in SQL.

For the variable, it uses a SQL parameter, to defend against SQL injection (no risk with the hard-coded string, unless you do it to yourself!).

So SQL CE must be treating these two differently.

Comment: When I use ToTraceString, the output is identical whether I use the variable or the string literal.

Comment: You sure you're looking at the right thing? http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/linq-to-entities-entity-sql-parameterized-store-queries-and-sql-injection/ I've seen the behavior I describe myself.

Comment: I'm definitely looking at the right thing. Both SQL strings are identical, and they're parameterized.

Comment: As best as I can tell, the ToTraceString function must be lying to me, since it returns the same string for the hard coded vs variable based query, yet one works and the other doesn't. So I'm going to give you credit. In the end, I see this as a bug in EF - at least on top of SQL CE.